# php Include - file in a folder

Tags: php, include

I'm using php include in the index file to include banner (graphic on my page).

The files are in the folders:

```
C:\Users\name\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\RemSysTempFls\ERIC\www\apachedft\htdocs\fender400\gk\index.php
```

RemSysTempFls\ERIC\www\apachedft\htdocs\fender400\banner.php

I am unable to include banner.php with the following:

```
include ('/fender400/banner.php');
```

and get the  errors (the page still runs):

> Warning: main(/fender400/banner.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /www/apachedft/htdocs/fender400/gk/index.php on
>   line 16
>
> Warning: main(): Failed opening '/fender400/banner.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/QOpenSys/php//lib/php') in
>   /www/apachedft/htdocs/fender400/gk/index.php on line 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the addresses of each of those files are correct?

Try it without the initial slash and see what it tells you

```
include ('fender400/banner.php');
```

or try:

```
include ('../../fender400/banner.php');
```

Comment: The addresses of each of those files are correct and after implementing suggested changes I keep getting the same Warning messages